# Yeoman Get Options

Tags: node.js, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I wrote this code:

```
this.option('username', {
    alias: 'u',
    name: 'Username',
    desc: 'A username used for Marketplace authentication',
    type: String,
    required: true
});

console.log(this.options.username);
```

I input the below in my terminal:

```
yo test -username MrZerg
```

I get back:

```
true
```

But I expect: "MrZerg"!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`yo` is using [meow](https://github.com/sindresorhus/meow) to parse command line input. I think you need a double `--` for options input. Try with `yo test --username MrZerg`

Comment: A shame meow doesn't support more common options similar to Unix user binaries.